# Jmeter - Simulate link(href) request (javascript)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am new to Jmeter. So far I have been successful in getting Jmeter to 
access my companies test site. Login and retrive results by sending 
parameters. However now I have a problem.

How can I get JMETER to simulate the href click this randomly generated links? Also the link 
is a popup link. An example of the link is posted below.

```
<a class="qmchild" href="javascript:goMenuLink(5,6);" name="SUBSearch by Batch"       id="SUBSearch by Batch" style="font-weight: normal;">Search by Batch</a>
```

I can extract "javascript:goMenuLink(5,6)" using CSS/XPATH/REGEX but the problem is how to send that HTTP Request from JMeter as I don't the target of the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is pure javascript - there is no point in using JMeter as it does not execute Javascript. Also, It does not make sense for JMeter to execute Javascript either as it is the tool for testing the Server performance. Javascript is going to run in your Browser-local machine.

However, if it is a HTTP request, ie - when you click on this link, if it hits a server to load the pop up - you should be able to record as you did with your login request. Try to see what is sent in the http request when you click on these links - Then I am sure you would be able to figure it out!